# Ubuntu Crash after start Windows 10 on Dual Boot

Tags: dual-boot, encryption, ssd, windows-10, crash

I have installed Windows 10 on my SSD m2, and every time I install Ubuntu on my laptop and next start Windows, with Dual Boot, Ubuntu partition breaks down and it shows this error.
[image]
If I dont start Windows, Ubuntu doesn't crash.
The problem is not with Nvidia because I use noveau.modeset=0 to boot while installing and change the drivers once installed.

**Things I have tried:**

-Create a partition in the SSD using the Ubuntu Installer.

-Create a partition in the SSD from Windows 10.

-Install Ubuntu in the HDD.

-Install Ubuntu 16.04, 18.04, 18.10, 18.04.2 LTS, Linux Mint...

But all of this attempts have finished with the same error (see photo)

I have the Secure Boot and Fast Boot disabled.

The laptop is Asus ROG-GLV753VD.

English is not my native language, sorry if I have errors with this.

Comment: Dual Boot advice:

I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.

Comment: Do you have a single SSD on your laptop? What is its capacity?  I assume you  have a single HDD.

Comment: @Marmayogi Yes, a single SSD (Samsung 970 EVO NVMe M.2 250 GB) and a single HDD on the SATA port.

Comment: How much disk space you allocate for Windows-10 and how much for Ubuntu 18.04. Have you decided?

Comment: @waltinator Thanks, I will read, I have a lot to learn

Comment: @Marmayogi In other times I have tried with 35gb for Ubuntu and 210 for Windows. But last time (now) I put 180gb for Windows and 50gb for Ubuntu.

Comment: Fine! windows-10 is 180 gb and ubuntu is 50 GB. Please read both the links [How can I install Ubuntu on Windows 10 laptop with two hard drives on separate drives?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1127364/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-on-windows-10-laptop-with-two-hard-drives-on-separate-d/1127412#1127412) and [Dual Boot Windows 10 and Linux Ubuntu on Separate SSD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033497/dual-boot-windows-10-and-linux-ubuntu-on-separate-ssd/1126970#1126970). In both the posts, I have answered in detail. If you have any questions, please let me know.  You will be good! Good luck!

Comment: If rebooting from Windows into Ubuntu is causing the problem you can check you have the most recent Windows driver installed: https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools/

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix recently tested, but still failing