# Dual boot windows on ssd and ubuntu on hdd

Tags: dual-boot

I have ssd 250gb and hdd 1tb. Now  i have both operating systems on hdd. I want to install windows10 on ssd and ubuntu on hdd?

Searching on internet i only find that dual boot is on hdd or ssd, not one on ssd and another one on hdd.

Is it possible and how i could do it?

Comment: You want to divide 250 SSD into two. Please first decide the size for both Windows and Ubuntu. Let us say 150 GB Windows and 100 GB for Ubuntu. Your 1 TB HDD with NTFS partition can be shared between Windows and Ubuntu. As 1 TB HDD is NTFS file system, this can be directly accessible to windows whereas Ubuntu needs them mounted in order to access.  Also, you  may want to 2 or 3 partitions on 1 TB HDD.

Comment: Please read this post wherein I answered in detail: [How can I install Ubuntu on Windows 10 laptop with two hard drives on separate drives?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1127364/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-on-windows-10-laptop-with-two-hard-drives-on-separate-d/1127412#1127412)

Comment: I think you didn't get me. I want only using ssd for windows and i dont want ubuntu to have anything with ssd. So what i want is windows to have all ssd for it self and some partiton of hdd

Comment: Fine, you can carve out a partition in 1 TB hard disk and go ahead and install Ubuntu. You may also have two or three partition with NTFS file system on the same 1 TB hard disk. You may refer my detailed answer in this post [Dual Boot Windows 10 and Linux Ubuntu on Separate SSD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033497/dual-boot-windows-10-and-linux-ubuntu-on-separate-ssd/1126970#1126970). Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- There is no problem in that.
- You can do that by:

  1. Fresh install of Windows on SSD.
  2. Shrink the Windows partitio and copy the Windows Partitions on SSD, either with [dd command](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/linux-dd-command-clone-disk-practical-example/) or [clonezilla](https://www.tecmint.com/migrate-windows-10-from-hdd-to-ssd-using-clonezilla/)

**Important:**  If copying
1. **Backup your data**
2. Read the tutorials.
3. Sum of all the windows partitions should be less than SSD size.
4. Keep the SSD as second disk so that the Windows does not overwrite the Ubuntu bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same configuration as you have, and I confirm it is possible.

I bought the laptop with Windows 10 installed. I created empty space for Ubuntu using Windows 10 and it's partitioning tool.

Then I install Ubuntu. During installation, I chose installer settings that allowed me to define the partitions as I wished. I specifically installed the SWAP partition on HDD and the rest of Ubuntu on empty space on SSD.

So in general, I would recommend to install Windows 10 first as you wish. Then partition with Windows tool to create empty space for Ubuntu. It makes Windows happy with it's own partition, probably less risky than partitioning directly from a third party tool while Windows is shut down. Last, use Ubuntu installer to define your partitions as you wish. Installer will show clearly Windows partitions, the different drives, the empty space on each drive.

But before doing anything, **backup your data**!!