# How to install Oracle Database Express Edition (XE) Release 18c on ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: oracle, database

I just downloaded Oracle Database Express Edition (XE) Release 18c and would like to install it on my Ubuntu 19.10. The archive in rpm format. How I can install it?

Comment: Why do you want to use in deb based OS a package for rpm based OS? Try this first:
https://askubuntu.com/q/1121649/925971